# Memory leak in python-igraph with induced_subgraph function?

Tags: python, memory, igraph

I'm working with igraph in Python and encountered a problem when calling induced_subgraph function a million times - the problem is, there is a consumption of memory.

```
import gc
import igraph
import resource

g = igraph.Graph(n=4, edges=[[0, 1], [0,2], [0, 3]])
mem = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

for i in range (1,1000001):
    igraph_list_v = [0,1,2,3]
    s = g.induced_subgraph(igraph_list_v)
    del s
    if i%100000 == 0:
        gc.collect()
        print(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss - mem)
        mem = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
```

Output:

```
0
4752
0
4752
0
4752
0
4752
0
4488
0
4752
0
4732
0
4752
0
4752
0
4752
```

Zeros are from gc.collect() function. Based on output, the induced_subgraph function consumes 4752 kilobytes every 100000 calls.

Printed memory is increasing with each print statement. This is a dummy case, but I call induced_subgraph function many million times and it breaks my script due to memory error. What is a possible workaround and what is actually reason for such behavior? Also keep in mind that I am on beginner level, so keep answer as simple as possible. Thank you for help!

Comment: Increasing how much? See [mre]. You can [edit] the post to include some of your print statements.

Comment: There was [a recent memory leak fix](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/503). You could try the development version (needs to be compiled from source) and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: Edited the code. I hope it is more clear now.